# change drawable of cursor in EditText

Tags: java, cursor, drawable

I try change drawable cursor in afterTextChanged() in different ways and in different sequences.
What am I doing wrong?
How can I change the cursor after entering a character in EditText ?

```
public class View extends ConstraintLayout {
private EditText editText;

 public View (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setTextCursorDrawable(R.drawable.first_cursor);
    editText.setCursorVisible(true);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {}
     
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           editText.setCursorVisible(false);
           editText.setTextCursorDrawable(null);
           editText.setTextCursorDrawable(R.drawable.second_cursor);
           requestLayout();
           editText.invalidate();
           invalidate();
           editText.setCursorVisible(true);
 }
```

In second cursor I want set padding for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's help me:

```
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:right="16px">
            <shape>
                <size
                    android:width="4px"
                    android:height="64px" />
                <solid android:color="@color/color1" />
                <corners android:radius="4px" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    
        <item
            android:id="@+id/end"
            android:left="@dimen/16px">
            <shape>
                <size
                    android:width="4px"
                    android:height="64px" />
                <solid android:color="@color/color1" />
                <corners android:radius="4px" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

cursor.xml

```
public class View extends ConstraintLayout {
private EditText editText;
private boolean isVisibleLayerEnd = false;

public View (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) getResources().
            getDrawable(R.drawable.cursor);
Drawable layerStart = drawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.start);
Drawable layerEnd = drawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.end);
layerEnd.setAlpha(0);
editText.setTextCursorDrawable(drawable);
editText.setCursorVisible(true);

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int 
    after) {}
 
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int 
    count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       if (editText.getText().length() >= 1 && !isVisibleLayerEnd) {
                layerStart.setAlpha(0);
                layerEnd.setAlpha(255);
                isVisibleLayerEnd = true;
            }
            if (mPrimaryEditText.getText().length() == 0) {
                layerStart.setAlpha(255);
                layerEnd.setAlpha(0);
                isVisibleLayerEnd = false;
            }
            editText.setCursorVisible(true);
     }
```